# Twitter/Facebook/LinkedIn buttons not showing up

Tags: facebook, wordpress, twitter, linkedin-api

I have been tasked with rebuilding a WordPress site... I am comfortable with PHP but WordPress seems to hold a few surprises, but I am learning.

However, the site that I am working on wants me to move their social media buttons from the bottom of the sidebar to the top, and wants the buttons to be more functional... currently, they are only linking to their profiles.

I went ahead and grabbed the official twitter buttons, as well as facebook and linkedin... I grabbed both major buttons (like and share) from each site.

After dropping all of these buttons into the proper position... NONE of them appear.  I have had *some* of them appear from time to time, but it appears sporadic and unpredictable; of them, the worst of the bunch appears to be LinkedIn.

Code is listed below, an is currently hosted at techbuildersgroup.com/GO/GO.html for those that would prefer to see the code in a live environment. (please, I know its ugly, its beta... and yes, its a table, but WP wasn't liking playing nice with my css... it will get better).

At this point, I am not even sure what is causing these not to appear, they seem to generally be iframes, and when I grab the link for them, they open perfectly fine directly in browser, but when embedded into the page they fail... could this be a WordPress issue?  Any way around it?  Anyone else see this happen before?

Thank you in advance for anyone able to help with this... it has been driving me nuts.

```
<!-- Social Media Buttons -->

<table style="border:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr style="padding:0px;margin:0px">
        <td  style="width:150px;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
            <h3>Follow Us!</h3>
        </td>
        <td  style="width:120px;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
            <h3><span style="text-align:right">Share Us!</span></h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- Twitter -->
<table style="border:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:150px;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
            <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
  src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/follow_button.html?screen_name=gonetworkstl&show_screen_name=false"
  style="width:150px; height:20px;display:inline;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
                    </iframe>
        </td>
        <td style="width:120px;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px;stackoverflow.com09<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
        src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?url=http://gonetworkstl.com"
        style="width:130px; height:20px;padding:0px;margin:0px;"></iframe>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- FaceBook -->
<table style="border:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:150px;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
            <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fgonetworkstl.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=150&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:20px;display:inline;padding:0px;margin:0px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        </td>
        <td style="width:120px;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
            <a name="fb_share"></a> 
                    <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
        type="text/javascript">
                    </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- LinkedIn -->
<table style="border:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:150px;border:0px;">
            <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="2229259" data-counter="right"></script>
        </td>
        <td style="width:120px;border:0px;">
            <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="IN/Share" data-url="http://gonetworkstl.com" data-counter="right"></script>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For the LinkedIn buttons, try including the `<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` tag in the `<head></head>` section of the page, and try using the full `src` value, adding in `http:` before the double slash.

Comment: Link is not working. Never had that many problems with CSS on wordpress, that's no excuse to use tables. :-D Never had any problems with social icons on wordpress either, so I suppose wordpress is not the issue.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry for the inaccurate link, that has now been fixed.

Comment: As for the tables, given that this was quickie test code, I started out with inline .css, and it was causing some issues.  Rather than hunt down a stray rule just for beta code, I just tossed the table in.

The tables will be gone once it becomes production code.

Comment: @Paul - Just tried that... also eliminated the additional script inclusion, given that the two buttons were trying to load the same file.

So far, no change.

Comment: @Paul - Actually, what is interesting is the note from Chrome's developer toolbox... it is listing 'Failed to load resource' for both LinkedIn's in.js as well as Facebook's FB.Share.  Have checked both URL's, and they appear to me to be accurate...

Comment: I see all the buttons at the link above

Comment: Wow... really?

I can't see any of them... using *any* browser.

Is anyone else seeing all the links?

Comment: Windows 7, Chrome 20: http://i.imgur.com/oHqyi.png

Comment: Bah, still one button missing, and still no explanation as to why... worse, on my end, NOTHING is showing.  However, it looks like the best answer I will find.... would be willing to mark it answered, but you need to 'reply' rather than add comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, you can style them with DIV's in your CSS stylesheet.

replace **XYZ** with your **URL**

```
<head>
<!-- Twitter -->
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>

<!-- Facebook-->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=187567691292898";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Linkedin -->    
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="facebook">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="XYZ" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="70" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</div>

<div id="linkedin">
    <script type="IN/Share" data-url="XYZ" data-counter="right"></script>
</div>

<div id="twitter">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="XYZ" data-lang="en" data-dnt="true">Tweet</a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow... Sorry for letting this one rot on the vine... this was not my intention.

Comment: Given that I was not able to get this to work this way on site, we went another route... which is probably I didn't notice when the question was answered.

Comment: No idea if your solution works or not, since this problem was long ago and far away... but I hate leaving responders unrewarded; so will mark your response as the answer... and sorry again for the wait.